# How to parse 東京都と埼玉県、北海道などにある会場も

Tags: parsing, particle-など

Regarding the Tokyo olympics:

> この大会では、新しく会場を建てるだけではなくて、**東京都と埼玉県、北海道などにある会場も**客の席を増やすなどの工事をして使う予定です。
>   In this competition, rather than just build new venues, there is a plan to use and increase the visitor seating at **venues in Tokyo and Saitama and places like Hokkaido**.

I'm not convinced by my translation of the bold part. It seems weird.

I think I should parse it like this:

> AとBとCも
>   A = 東京都
>   B = 埼玉県
>   C = 北海道などにある会場

1) Since there is no で particle would I be correct in thinking that these places (A, B and C) are the **subject** of 増やす, i.e. も replaces が? So, "A, B and C will increase seating ..." rather than "increase seating **in** A, B and C". Otherwise I would have expected AとBとC**で**も. I'm not convinced by this though. How can a 会場 have a will to do something.

2) The use of など confuses me. It list two very specific areas and then says 'oh, and also venues in places like this enormous island that occupies a large fraction of Japan's land mass'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 「この大会{たいかい}では、新{あたら}しく会場{かいじょう}を建{た}てるだけではなくて、東京都{とうきょうと}と埼玉県{さいたまけん}、北海道{ほっかいどう}などにある会場も客{きゃく}の席{せき}を増{ふ}やすなどの工事{こうじ}をして使{つか}う予定{よてい}です。」

The first thing I must say (just in case you have not noticed it) is the fact that this writing is fairly **informal**.  Why I say that?  I do because of the informal (and easy) word choices -- 建てる、なくて、客の席、増やす and 使う.  In fact, I am wondering if this was written for children.

In more conventional news reporting, those words would be replaced by 建設{けんせつ}する、なく、観客席{かんきゃくせき}、増加{ぞうか}させる and 使用{しよう}する (with possible variations).

The point of what I am trying to convey here is that I would **not** expect very strict grammar-like grammar from this writing.  I would only expect a conversational style of writing.  I would like you to know that my answer will be based on these observations of mine.

> 1) Since there is no で particle would I be correct in thinking that these places (A, B and C) are the subject of 増やす, i.e. も replaces が? So, "A, B and C will increase seating ..." rather than "increase seating in A, B and C". Otherwise I would have expected AとBとCでも. I'm not convinced by this though. How can a 会場 have a will to do something.

No, the three places mentioned are **not** the subject of 「増やす」.  The subject is unmentioned **as usual**.  It would be the implied "**people directly involved in the Olympics**".

The 「も」 is used because the sentence mainly talks about two different "actions".  One is to build brand-new facilities.  The other is to renovate existing facilities.  「も」 was used because the word 「会場」 was used a second time.

You mentioned 「AとBとCでも」, but using 「と」 or 「や」 multiple times in a short list is considered fairly wordy and awkward.

> 2) The use of など confuses me. It list two very specific areas and then says 'oh, and also venues in places like this enormous island that occupies a large fraction of Japan's land mass'.

「東京都と埼玉県、北海道など」 is actually a good way to phrase an unexhaustive list.  「など」 is used because there are a couple of more prefectures (besides the three mentioned) in which existing facilities will be renovated for the Olympics.  The author could have also used:

・「東京、埼玉、北海道など」

・「東京、埼玉、そして北海道など」

I did not get the "oh, and also" kind of feeling from the phrasing at all.  「など」 is needed unless you mention **all** of the prefectures where facilities will be renovated.

Comment: I wasn't aware that the whole of Hokkaido was a single prefecture. It makes much more sense now. You are right about the childish writing. It's from the NHK's so-called Easy News. I'm afraid the real news is far too tough for me at the moment.